# Android -- can System.out.println() significantly decrease performance like it does on a PC

Tags: android, performance

System calls are very expensive. `System.out.println()` can bring an app to its knees if ran inside a loop. Does it affect the console-less android similarly?

Comment: Most of the reason `System.out.println()` is expensive is **actually displaying the output in the console**, which is slow. If you redirect output, all of a sudden it's much faster. It isn't because it is a system call, system calls are made all the time to do just about everything that interacts with anything outside your application.

Comment: If you decide to test this, please report back.

Comment: In my OS course we measured the execution time of a c++ program that wrote to nothing (dev/null) a million times and compared it with a program that iterated through the same loop but didn't make the empty system calls, and the performance difference was substantial.

Comment: System calls are expensive? I wonder how our OSes even function then.

Comment: @farm ostrich: That's not a fair comparison. Try calling an empty function instead. Even that's not fair. You are calling a function that does something, of course there is going to be time spent doing it. Writing to `/dev/null` still does everything that writing to anywhere else does short of actually hitting the hard drive. I'm also curious exactly how substantial 'substantial' is.

Comment: @Matthew system calls require going into the kernel, ya? That takes time. A user level function call doesn't have that overhead.

Comment: @farm ostrich: It takes time, I just seriously doubt it takes 'substantial' time unless you're seriously abusing it. Printing in a tight loop is horrible design to start with, but it's the only way you'd get a noticeable slowdown, even printing to the screen. 5-10 CPU cycles isn't 'substantial'. Anyway, it seems a bit of a moot point. If there's no console on Android, why make the call in the first place? Debugging? Wrap in conditional compilation statements and your problem vanishes for production builds.

Comment: @Matt I didn't ask because it has any practical application. It was just a curiosity because it doesn't have a console but it does have console output which is a peculiar situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran a quick test for you using a 10000000 iteration loop.

Empty ~ 200ms
System.out.println() ~ 5600ms
System.out.println("abcdefghijklmnop") ~ 90000ms

Up to you apply that to your situation whether it is acceptable or not.

Btw it doesn't do nothing, it prints to the device log

Comment: Interesting ... The older versions didnt print anything, you had to switch it to Log.d or something ... good find!